# Use enum with number

Tags: android, enums

I know there are many alternatives to reach what I wish, but I wont this solution because it is the most comfortable to me. I wish to use enum that starts with number, like so.

```
public enum Quality {
    1080p,
    720p,
    BlueRay //this one OK
}
```

And then use it like so when converting to string:

```
Quality.1080p.name();
```

Why it is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Java language doesn't allow variable names to start with a number-  just a letter or underscore.  Any character after the first may be a number.  The main reason for this is to make parsing easier, and prevent situations where the parser can't tell if a symbol is a number or a variable name.

For example, if numbers were valid at the start of a variable I could do the following:

```
String 1 = "string";
System.out.println(1);
```

Does this print 1 or "string"?  They avoid the problem by not allowing it.  Many (most?) languages have that restriction.